# Google App Engine: "No module named google.appengine.ext"

Tags: google-app-engine

Im getting this error when testing my main.py GAE application:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext import db
ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext
```

I read a lot about it but i can´t find the answer...any ideas or help?
Thank you guys!!

Comment: What do you see in `/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine`? It might be worth it to try reinstalling the SDK.

Comment: I see 12 items: some folders and 2 _init files, should i unistall appenginelauncher and reinstall it? Thanks!

Comment: Im getting this too: ImportError: cannot import name db

Comment: How are you launching your application? (Command line or GUI launcher?)

Comment: googleappenginelauncher

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem when testing my app. I found that my `/usr/local/google_appengine` contained the `google` python module, so I added that path to my `$PYTHONPATH` environment variable. You can do this in 2 ways:

1. In your console, type `export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/google_appengine"`. This will add it to your PYTHONPATH for this console session.
2. In your shell profile file (perhaps `~/.bash_profile`), add a line like this:

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/google_appengine"
   ```

   Then either open a new console session or reload your profile with `source ~/.bash_profile` (or whatever your file is)

You may have to modify this because a) your "google_appengine" folder is in a different location (not `/usr/local`) or b) your OS separates paths differently (I think windows uses `;` instead of `:` -- I'm on a Mac)

Comment: So this worked for me, but I had to then `pip install` every library that was missing. It didn't make all the GAE builtin libraries (e.g. Jinja2) available. So kudos for solving the specific issue, but the bigger problem still unsolved. Kind of weak-ass of Google tho, since it seems that a lot of people are having this problem in spite of following the installation instructions...

Answer (score 7):

I would like to add a case that I have faced. My OS is MAC.

The Google App Engine would create a link under `/usr/local/google_appengine`.

I added the above path to `PYTHONPATH`, it still don't work. After some trail, I found I had installed **protobuf** which is also under development of *google*, please check

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial

It will create a folder under `side_packages` also named `google`. So if you try to `import google`, it is actually importing **protobuf**.

So one possible solution for this is temporarily uninstall **protobuf**:

`pip uninstall protobuf`

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the problem come from the directory `/google_appengine` that is not always at the right spot, so python cannot find it (through `PYTHONPATH`).

1. Find the location of the google_appengine directory by running

   `find / -name google_appengine -type d`
2. Once you found it (e.g. : `/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine`), run:

   `export PYTHONPATH=:/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine`

This solved my problem.

Comment: find / -name google_appengine -type d isn't returning anything. Or rather is taking very long to find the file. what may be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the answer, but can you try adding the following code to debug:

```
import logging

import google

logging.info("google path: {}.".format(google.__file__))
```

Compare this path to the location of the App Engine SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will print all google python lib paths

```
import google
print "google path: {}.".format(google.__path__)
```

running the code on my machine prints this

> google path:
>   ['/usr/local/Cellar/protobuf/2.6.1/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google',
>   '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google'].

this is not the same as looking for google appengine installation directories.
On my mac, the installer creates sym links

```
/usr/local/google_appengine
```

incase you are unit testing, you probably need to add the path to your code

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/usr/local/google_appengine')
sys.path.insert(1, '/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib')
```