# "ImportError: No module named webapp2" after Linux SDK upgrade (1.9.35 -> 1.9.38)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

After upgrading my GAE Python Linux SDK from version 1.9.35 to 1.9.38 my application stopped working, all requests are failing in similar manner:

```
ERROR    2016-06-10 17:55:06,100 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/home/dancorn/src/apartsw/main/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    import webapp2
ImportError: No module named webapp2
INFO     2016-06-10 17:55:06,102 module.py:788] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I first thought that I somehow screwed up my PyCharm config, but simply rolling back to 1.9.35 (by pointing my `/usr/local/google_appengine` symlink back to the respective SDK version dir) got things back working as expected.

The [SDK release notes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/release-notes) don't appear to indicate anything related.

I found [a similar report](http://kawahara.ca/gae-python-importerror-no-module-named-webapp2/), but the suggested fix (rolling back) is not really acceptable down the road.

I also found this post, but I don't have protobuf (explicitly) installed: [How to solve a webapp2 import error after upgrading Google App Engine launcher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583769/how-to-solve-a-webapp2-import-error-after-upgrading-google-app-engine-launcher). Still chewing on the related posts which led me to this potentially related delta in the SDK, which I'll investigate next:

```
diff google_appengine_1.9.35/_python_runtime.py google_appengine_1.9.38/_python_runtime.py
71a72,75
>   if 'google' in sys.modules:
>     google_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'google')
>     google_module = sys.modules['google']
>     google_module.__path__.append(google_path)
74,77c78
< 
< 
<   if 'google' in sys.modules:
<     del sys.modules['google']
---
>     google_module.__file__ = google_path
```

Any other investigation leads?

Comment: By any chance you have installed google protobuf?

Comment: @gipsy Not intentionally, I'm not using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: The issue was fixed in SDK version 1.9.40.

The issue is already known to Google, introduced in 1.9.37:

- [the acknowledged report](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/LucknWk8iaQ) with more info
- tracked as [GAE Issue 12963](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12963).

From the report thread, as per Jon Parrot:

> Thanks everyone for reporting this. We've reproduced the issue and and
>   fix is incoming. It won't be in the next SDK release (38), but likely
>   will be in 39 or 40.

Until the fix is released an earlier unaffected SDK version (like 1.9.36) can be found [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/appengine-sdks/featured).