# Google Appengine Hello World gets HTTP 500 Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-development-server

I created a new project in Google Appengine but when I try to access it through localhost I get a HTTP 500 Error.  My browser says 'localhost is currently unable to handle this request.'  The following is my code for the new project:

app.yaml:

```
application: hello-world
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Copyright 2007 Google Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

When I run the following command on command line:

```
python "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py" "C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\Hello World\hello-world"
```

I get the error

```
  import webapp2

ImportError: No module named webapp2

INFO     2016-06-18 15:29:37,092 module.py:788] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: did you run the dev-appserver?  if yes, What port is it running on?  What localhost url are you requesting?

Comment: Yes I tried running dev-appserver but I get the following error: 
import webapp2
ImportError: No module named webapp2

I am using port 8080 and the url is http://localhost:8080/.

Comment: Two things I would suggest trying.  First, try running your program through app engine, and not from the command line.  Second, you might want to try installing and using Python 2.7 instead of 2.5.

Comment: @coralv I tried both running through app engine and the command line.  I also do have Python 2.7 installed instead of 2.5.  Is there someone wrong with my code that indicates otherwise?

Comment: What is the error log ? 500 should have error log in the console, assuming the request is served by the dev app server.

Comment: @JSGandora, it was my mistake.  I misread the part of your code that says Python 2.7.

Comment: @marcadian the error log is the following: 

  import webapp2

ImportError: No module named webapp2

INFO     2016-06-18 15:29:37,092 module.py:788] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - (I will update the original post with the error log as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: the issue was fixed in SDK version 1.9.40.

There is [a GAE issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12963) causing exactly this behaviour introduced in SDK version 1.9.37, see ["ImportError: No module named webapp2" after Linux SDK upgrade (1.9.35 -> 1.9.38)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755195/importerror-no-module-named-webapp2-after-linux-sdk-upgrade-1-9-35-1-9-38).

If your SDK version is 1.9.37 or 1.9.38 downgrade to 1.9.36, which you can find [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/appengine-sdks/featured). At least until the fix gets released.