# Local development of Google App Engine not importing built-in library

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I followed the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/quickstart) then I simply clone `hello_world` from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/hello_world/). I already downloaded google_appengine sdk from [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python). I extract it and now I have folder `google_appengine` alongside with `hello_world`

so I execute it like this:

[image]

It runs well apparently, until I start to request to localhost:8080.
then I got this error:

[image]

what's wrong with it? did I miss something?
google said that I can use the built-in library without manually install it with `pip`.

PS: it works when I just deploy it to my project on Google. and also it works if I manually install webapp2 inside `lib` inside `hello_world` like described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_library) then request it locally.

my python version Python 2.7.6 on ubuntu 14.04 32bit

Please if anybody can solve this I would be appreciate it.

Comment: As I remember you have to install it manually on your local machine. Not sure if it's a bug or not. UPDATE: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#local_development – no webapp2 lister here though, but I can confirm that I have to install it manually.

Comment: it should be provided by dev_appserver.py because I see the built-in lib in `google_appengine/lib` but somehow not included on environment path

Comment: webapp2 listed here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27. your link is lib that should be installed independently, it's not built-in libs

Comment: `lxml`and many others are in both lists, so at least some of built-in libs you have to install manually.

Comment: I think you missed the point, it says that `lxml` `matplotlib` and so on should be installed manually due to platform-dependent, so it means `webapp2` `jinja2` etc doesn't need to be installed manually, right?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is [acknowledged](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12963) bug in app engine SDK. As a temporary workaround, you may try this steps:

> Uninstalling the following PIP packages resolved this issue for me.
>
> `sudo pip uninstall gcloud`
>
> `sudo pip uninstall googleapis-common-protos`
>
> `sudo pip uninstall protobuf`
>
> Credit to this thread:
>   https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=nl#!topic/google-appengine/LucknWk8iaQ

Be sure to use correct executable of pip if you use virtualenv or have multiple python versions installed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Dmytro Sadovnychyi for the answer. It doesn't work for me to uninstall those packages because I never installed it before, But that makes me think maybe built-in library conflict with other package so I decide to create `Virtual Environment`. just fresh environment no need to install any package.

activate the environment then execute `dev_appserver.py hello_world` now it works

for now I'll stick with it until next update like said [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/LucknWk8iaQ)

Comment: Alternatively you can just use the 1.9.36 SDK until the fix is out, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840104/google-appengine-hello-world-gets-http-500-error