# GAE import errors; sys.path shows wrong path for appengine libraries

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, jinja2

I'm developing a web app for Google App Engine in Python on Windows 10. Everything was working fine when my main.py was just serving templates.

```
import os
import urllib
from google.appengine.api import users
import jinja2
import webapp2

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)
```

But then I tried to add cloud storage, and got import errors no matter what library I tried. So I removed those references from main.py, and now I get an error with jinja2, which had been working fine!

```
ImportError: No module named jinja2
```

I don't remember everything I tried, but here's what I do know:

- jinja2 is installed; attempts to pip install/upgrade says it's already installed and up-to-date, and I see it in `c:\python27\lib\site-packages`.
- `PYTHONPATH=C:\python27;c:\python27\lib;C:\Python27\DLLS` for system and user.
- At one point I had installed GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient with PIP into my app's lib directory per [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#downloading_the_client_library). It didn't work (the module failed to import), so I also tried adding `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "lib"))` but it didn't help. **I think this is when I started getting the jinja2 import error.** So I removed the statement from main.py. Still getting the jinja2 import error. I tried `pip uninstall GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient` but it said it wasn't installed, so I tried just deleting the lib directory. Still getting the jinja2 import error.
- Have tried restarting the service and rebooting my machine.

EDIT:

I stripped main.py all the way to the new project template,

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

and now I get an import error for webapp2:

```
ImportError: No module named webapp2
```

EDIT 2:

By inserting this at the top of my main.py,

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

I can see the wrong path for all the google packages:

```
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\lib\\webapp2-2.5.2', 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\lib\\pycrypto-2.6', 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\lib\\jinja2-2.6', 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\lib\\markupsafe-0.15', 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\lib\\setuptools-0.6c11', 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\lib\\protorpc-1.0', 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\lib\\webob-1.1.1', 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\lib\\yaml-3.10'
```

They are actually in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib`

I don't know why I didn't have this problem before I tried to install that one package, but this may be related to [a reported google issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12963).

Comment: What does the `libraries` section of your `app.yaml` look like?

Comment: @mgilson libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"

- name: pycrypto
  version: latest
  
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

Comment: I should clarify that it works fine when I deploy it. It is only running it locally that fails. BTW, I have tried repairing the app engine sdk and python installations and it still fails.

Comment: After UNINSTALLING the app engine sdk 1.9.38 and reinstalling version 1.9.36 the import error went away. I was also able to reinstall the cloud storage library as described above and it works with my live CS when deployed. So the issue may be a combination of the app engine cloud storage client and sdk v 1.9.38, related to google issue https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12963. Someone added an answer to this effect but it seems to have disappeared.

Comment: I just undeleted it - I misinterpreted your comment as the post not answering your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: the issue was fixed in SDK version 1.9.40.

There is [a GAE issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12963) causing exactly this behaviour introduced in SDK version 1.9.37, see ["ImportError: No module named webapp2" after Linux SDK upgrade (1.9.35 -> 1.9.38)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755195/importerror-no-module-named-webapp2-after-linux-sdk-upgrade-1-9-35-1-9-38).

If your SDK version is 1.9.37 or 1.9.38 downgrade to 1.9.36, which you can find [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/appengine-sdks/featured). At least until the fix gets released.

Comment: I mentioned that issue above, but didn't think it was quite the same because I've been running on 1.9.37-8 for six weeks with no such issues. Also removing protobuf didn't help. I'm going to try uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: Google agrees it is the same issue and merge it in.

Answer (score 0):

Summary:

The webapp2 and jinja2 import errors are caused by sys.path corruption, a result of a GAE defect present in versions 1.9.37 or 1.9.38. It only impacts development; deployed versions should work. It can occur immediately upon upgrading or after attempting to install other items.

Solutions:

- Downgrading the AppEngineSDK to 1.9.36 **worked for me**.
- The GAE defect will be fixed at some point after 1.9.38. Check for [Issue 12963](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12963) for status.
- Per [Google issue 13084](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13084), another workaround is to manually patch sys.path in appengine_config.py. [Docs here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig).