# Not able to import entities into datastore emulator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, emulation

I'm trying to restore a backup of my datastore entities into the emulator running on localhost.

I'm using the guide from this location https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/emulator-export-import 
This is what I have managed to do so far.

```sh
#start the emulator
gcloud beta emulators datastore start --store-on-disk --data-dir "./datastore-emulator" --project=my-project
```

```sh
# set the environment
$(gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init)

# initiate the restore operation
curl -X POST localhost:8081/v1/projects/my-project:import \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"input_url":"/home/bogdan/workspace/myCopy/2019-08-19-23-00/2019-08-19-23-00.overall_export_metadata"}'
```

at this point I can see that the emulator detected a connection and this is the log snippet

```sh
[datastore] Dev App Server is now running.
[datastore] 
[datastore] The previous line was printed for backwards compatibility only.
[datastore] If your tests rely on it to confirm emulator startup,
[datastore] please migrate to the emulator health check endpoint (/). Thank you!
[datastore] The health check endpoint for this emulator instance is http://localhost:8081/Sep 02, 2019 3:45:11 PM io.gapi.emulators.grpc.GrpcServer$3 operationComplete
[datastore] INFO: Adding handler(s) to newly registered Channel.
[datastore] Sep 02, 2019 3:45:11 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
[datastore] INFO: Detected non-HTTP/2 connection.
[datastore] Sep 02, 2019 3:45:11 PM io.gapi.emulators.grpc.GrpcServer$3 operationComplete
[datastore] INFO: Adding handler(s) to newly registered Channel.
[datastore] Sep 02, 2019 3:45:11 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpVersionRoutingHandler channelRead
[datastore] INFO: Detected HTTP/2 connection.
```

and after about 5 minutes of waiting

```
[datastore] Exception in thread "grpc-default-executor-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
[datastore]     at java.util.Collections.unmodifiableList(Collections.java:1289)
[datastore]     at com.google.storage.onestore.v3.proto2api.OnestoreEntity$Path.<init>(OnestoreEntity.java:8573)
[datastore]     at com.google.storage.onestore.v3.proto2api.OnestoreEntity$Path.<init>(OnestoreEntity.java:8504)
[datastore]     at com.google.storage.onestore.v3.proto2api.OnestoreEntity$Path$1.parsePartialFrom(OnestoreEntity.java:10145)
[datastore]     at com.google.storage.onestore.v3.proto2api.OnestoreEntity$Path$1.parsePartialFrom(OnestoreEntity.java:10133)
[datastore]     at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:969)
[datastore]     at com.google.storage.onestore.v3.proto2api.OnestoreEntity$EntityProto.<init>(OnestoreEntity.java:13508)
[datastore]     at com.google.storage.onestore.v3.proto2api.OnestoreEntity$EntityProto.<init>(OnestoreEntity.java:13407)
[datastore]     at com.google.storage.onestore.v3.proto2api.OnestoreEntity$EntityProto$1.parsePartialFrom(OnestoreEntity.java:15888)
[datastore]     at com.google.storage.onestore.v3.proto2api.OnestoreEntity$EntityProto$1.parsePartialFrom(OnestoreEntity.java:15876)
[datastore]     at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:57)
[datastore]     at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:20)
[datastore]     at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.LevelDBLogReaderChannel.readProtoMessage(LevelDBLogReaderChannel.java:65)
[datastore]     at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.ExportImportUtil.parseEntityProtoFile(ExportImportUtil.java:157)
[datastore]     at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.ExportImportUtil.fetchEntities(ExportImportUtil.java:59)
[datastore]     at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.admin.v1.DatastoreAdminV1Emulator.importEntities(DatastoreAdminV1Emulator.java:115)
[datastore]     at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.admin.v1.DatastoreAdminGrpcAdapter$1.importEntities(DatastoreAdminGrpcAdapter.java:55)
[datastore]     at com.google.datastore.admin.v1.DatastoreAdminGrpc$MethodHandlers.invoke(DatastoreAdminGrpc.java:1040)
[datastore]     at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$UnaryServerCallHandler$UnaryServerCallListener.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:171)
[datastore]     at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerCallImpl.java:283)
[datastore]     at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1HalfClosed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:711)
[datastore]     at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
[datastore]     at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
[datastore]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[datastore]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[datastore]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[datastore] Sep 02, 2019 3:47:35 PM io.gapi.emulators.netty.HttpHandler$1 onError
[datastore] INFO: Exception when handling request: UNKNOWN
```

Also the was not database file created at `./datastore-emulator/WEB-INF/appengine-generated`

Comment: edited the tags, to give proper visibility

Comment: did you manage to resolve this? I am facing the same issue, I have a 16gb machine, so it should not be a problem, but keep running into the same issue

Comment: @bool.dev Sadly I was not able to get past this. The out of memory error is probably due to bad implementation of the emulator. I'm speculating here but my backup is over 7 GB. I'm also dealing with some legacy entities witch ware bad designed from the start and some of them are quite big on their own. What I did in the end was 1.create a new project on google console, 2. restore the backup in the new project and then 3. configured the local running app to connect to the live database for the new project. 4 debug using localhost with datastore connected to this new project

Comment: I was able to overcome the memory error by exporting `export JAVA="java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"` this is because the script that runs the emulator `./platform/cloud-datastore-emulator/cloud_datastore_emulator` uses this environment variable that default to just `java` if not defined.