# How to fix appengine ImportError: No module named protobuf?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, protocol-buffers, python-import

I have the following folders structure:

```
myappdir
  - libs
    - somelib
      script1.py
      script2.py
    - google
      - protobuf
          __init__.py
          message.py
          ...
      __init__.py
      ...
    app.yaml
    appengine_config.py
    ...
```

And the following files content -

**appengine_config.py**:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('libs')
```

**script1.py**:

```
from somelib.script2 import Something
```

**script2.py**:

```
from google.protobuf import message
```

In result I get:

```
  File "myappdir/libs/somelib/script1.py", line 34, in <module>
    from somelib.script2 import Something
  File "myappdir/libs/somelib/script2.py", line 38, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import message
ImportError: No module named protobuf
```

What is wrong with my setup?

Comment: I notice you're not showing an `__init__.py` in the `protobuf` folder.

Comment: @user2357112, it is there - fixed the questions. Thanks.

Comment: potentially related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755195/importerror-no-module-named-webapp2-after-linux-sdk-upgrade-1-9-35-1-9-38

Answer (score 0):

Change the lines in your **appengine_config.py** file, from:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('libs')
```

to:

```
import sys
import os.path
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'libs'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found @Daniel's answer to already be implemented in my setup, but still had the problem.  [This github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/1436#issuecomment-185641691) comment helped me.  Adding the following to **appengine_config.py** solved the problem for me:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
import google.protobuf; print(google.protobuf.__version__)
```

change `lib` to `libs` depending on your project directory naming.