# Google App Engine Launcher (Python) - ImportError: No module named webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I havent used app engine in a while and decided to give it a shot again. It used to work just fine but now I can not seem to get it to work on my local machine.

The error log says the following.

---

```
import webapp2

ImportError: No module named webapp2

INFO     2016-12-17 20:51:12,707 module.py:788] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

---

When I deploy the application it works just fine. I just can't seem to get this to work on my local machine. I need it to work on my machine so I can debug.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to 1.9.37, and this caused webapp2 to stop working. I just downgraded back to the previous version available 1.9.49 - 2016-11-30 and it started working again.

If you are having issues with this, downgrade back.

Cheers!

Comment: A bit confusing in what you call upgrade/downgrade, but yes, known issue w/ SDK versions between 1.9.37 and 1.9.40: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755195/importerror-no-module-named-webapp2-after-linux-sdk-upgrade-1-9-35-1-9-38/37764786#37764786